# Synchronizing two concurrent network calls within AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, android-asynctask

I'm trying to make multiple concurrent HTTP GET calls which might return a response after different amount of time.
Once I have the data, I use it to create custom Adapter for a ListView. Since there is a high risk of NullPointerException, I need to make sure all the data is there, before I try and create the Adapter.
The HTTP calls are currently done with AsyncTask, which is convenient for doing them in background and later calling the UI thread to update the Views. But they're not concurrent - each call is executed after the previous one finished.

What I'm struggling with, is making sure that all the HTTP calls have returned a response before I create my adapter, while still maintaining concurrency.

Is there a way to run multiple, concurrent network calls and having the onPostExecute method do its thing after *all* of the concurrent HTTP calls have finished?

Or do I need to use more complex Threads, Locks, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## If you don't need the HTTP calls' responses

A [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) may do the trick for you. You initialize it with a count, and then call `countDown()`, which returns immediately, after each HTTP calls. On the `onPostExecute` side, `await()` blocks until `countDown()` has been invoked `count` times.

So:

- construct the `CountDownLatch` with the number of HTTP calls in the `AsyncTask`'s constructor
- call `latch.countDown()` after each HTTP call
- the thread invoking `onPostExecute` invokes `latch.await()`, which will block until all the above threads have completed their HTTP calls

## If you *do* need the responses

The above will work (there's a happens-before relationship between each `countDown()` and `await()` returning), but there's another way.

Wrap each HTTP call in a `Callable<Response>`, and submit that to an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html); it'll instantly give you back a `Future<Response>`, which you can then give to the object that defines `onPostExecute`. That method can get the actual response with `Response r = future.get()`, which will block until that specific callable has finished. If you do that for all of the HTTP calls, then after you call `futureWhatever.get()` for each of those futures, you'll be sure that the HTTP calls have all finished.

One advantage with this method is that `onPostExecute` doesn't have to block until all of the HTTP calls have completed; it can make progress until the one it needs at that moment has completed. For instance, if it does:

```
Future callA = httpA.get();
processCallA(callA); // this could take a while
Future callB = httpB.get();
...
```

... then `processCallA` can do its thing even as HTTP call B is completing, as long as HTTP call A has already completed.

Comment: Hmm, the CountDownLatch seems elegant. I could lock the AsyncThread doInBackground thread until all concurrent HTTP calls have finished. Then release the the lock, and create my Adapter in onPostExecute. If I understand the concept correctly, that is.
I'll try it out tomorrow - it's getting really late here. Either way, it looks promising - thanks a lot.